# Wait till captcha is manually entered and click on sign in button in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Wait till captcha is manually entered and click on sign in button in selenium python.

Since captcha cannot be bypassed, I want the browser to wait till it is manually entered and continue automation by clicking on Sign in button.

I tried below:

```
btnSignIn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Sign in"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(btnSignIn))
```

It is not working..please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide the website you are trying this on?

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the website details.

Comment: Are their url the same?

Answer (score 0):

EC.element_to_be_clickable should be checking if an element is clickable. If you add the click event to that btnSignIn, it is no longer referencing the element but the action. Try the below code

```
btnSignIn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Sign in"]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(btnSignIn))
btnSignIn.click()
```

Comment: it is not continuing with next step once captcha is verified.